# Error in query with Synch DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

I have synchronized two De from sales Cloud successfully and I'm now trying to run a query using them. I get an error message which tells they are unknown. 
I wonder which can be the error causing this issue.

As this query will have to populate a new data extension , I kindly ask you to confirm this is the correct process:
1. create a DE manually inserting all the fields I need (they will be a selection of those in the synchronized DE)
1. write the query with automation
2. create an automation which import data from query to the standard DE created at point 1

I thank you all for the help, G

Comment: is this in a child BU? you would need to add ENT.  ENT.contact_salesforce

Comment: can you provide the query syntax?

Comment: Hi, the first I'm trying to create a standard DE from a Synch one, with a shorter list of attribute and option Overwrite. This is the syntax SELECT PersonEmail, LastName, FirstName, Name, IsSubscribed__c
FROM Account_Salesforce. The Account_Salesforce is the sync DE. the query should send data to a Standard DE I have created with the exact fields you see in the query. Thanks for helping so much

Comment: @DavidDevoy  are you able to help please? this is the synthax SELECT Id, PersonEmail, LastName, FirstName, Name, IsSubscribed__c FROM Account_Salesforce. the Id is the primary key. I have the same issue on another DE (called Items) where the primary Key is the OrderID related to these products. Thanks again

Comment: You need to add ent. In front of your Salesforce de as I previously suggested

Comment: Hi   @EazyE we do not have child BU and inserting the ent. I got an error message in the syntax. We don't think this is the solution.

Comment: Do the DataTypes and Nullable setting for the PersonEmail, LastName, FirstName, Name, IsSubscribed__c field match the target?  I suspect the source DE contains null data in one of these fields, but the target DE is configured as a required field (aka nullsable not checked)

Comment: The issue could be related to the IsSubscribed__c field.  Is this a boolean field?  Try removing the IsSubscribed__c field from you query and make this field nullable in your target DE.  Does the same SQL error occur?

Comment: @DavidDevoy you are write I has some null fields which were required in the DE. Thanks for your help so much

Comment: You should modify your question to include your query and also any errors you are receiving